# Magento 1.9: Amasty Improved Layered Navigation position in product list page

Tags: xml, magento, navigation, layered

I would like to place the block "Amasty Improved Layered Navigation" in the product list page, exactly between the toolbar and the list itself but for how hard I tried changing both the phtml and xml file, I did not succeed. Does anyone have any idea how to do? 
thanks
ligrex

Comment: On top of category page or product detail page?

Comment: Category page. Just between toolbar (with sort command) and product list....

Answer (score 0):

Add following to local.xml or page.xml between layout tags:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="core/template" name="amasty.block.name" template="path/to/amasty_template.phtml" after="product_list_toolbar"/>
    </reference>        
</catalog_category_view>
```

Change `name` and `template` to desired values.

Comment: Hi Gerard, thank you.
I tried this but it doesn't work. Something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: <page_two_columns_left translate="label">
<catalog_category_view>
 <reference name="product_list">
<block type="core/template" name="amshopby.navtop" template="amasty/amshopby/view_top.phtml" after="product_list_toolbar"/>
</reference>
</catalog_category_view>        
<label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
<action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
</reference>
</page_two_columns_left>